# Ошибка ORA-00911 при выполнении запроса

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

У меня есть 3 формы с таблицами которые загружаются с ORACLE.
При нажатии на кнопку в одной из форм должен выполняться следующий запрос:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection connection = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(con.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "UPDATE issuence " +
                                            "SET issue_item_name = ( " +
                                              "SELECT sklad.item_name " +
                                              "FROM sklad " +
                                              "WHERE issuence.sklad_item_id = sklad.item_id) " +
                                            "WHERE EXISTS ( " +
                                              "SELECT 1 " +
                                              "FROM sklad " +
                                              "WHERE issuence.sklad_item_id = sklad.item_id); ";


                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

        }
```

Но вместо этого у меня появляется ошибка ORA-00911.
Пробовал убирать точку с запятой в конце запроса, но тогда приложение намертво зависает.

Comment: попробуйте удалить `;` в конце

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот это должно работать побыстрее.

```
command.CommandText = 
"merge into ISSUENCE d                                     " +
"using (                                                   " +
"    select                                                " +
"        i.rowid as r,                                     " +
"        s.item_name as issue_item_name                    " +
"    from                                                  " +
"        ISSUENCE i                                        " +
"        join SKLAD s                                      " +
"            on i.sklad_item_id = s.item_id                " +
"    where                                                 " +
"        decode(i.issue_item_name, s.item_name, 0) is null " +
") s                                                       " +
"on (d.rowid = s.r)                                        " +
"when matched then update set                              " +
"    d.issue_item_name = s.issue_item_name                 ";
```